# how i can make that the thread sleeps or wait 5 or whatever sec

Tags: c++

i have a programm in thta the user gives a number how much numbers will be generatet but the programm makes that to fast somthing like 20 or 40 same numbers per sec the programm using the time of the pc

here is my code

```
#include <iostream>;
#include <ctime>;

int i;
int z;

int main() {
    std::cout << "pls enter a number how much numbers will be generatet" << 
std::endl;
    std::cin >> z;

    while (true){
        srand(time(0)); 
        rand();
        rand();
        rand();
        std::cout << rand() << std::endl;
        i++;
        if (i == z) {
            break;
        }
    //system must sleep
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "how i can make that the thread sleeps"
-  [std::this_thread::sleep_for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for)

Comment: You should only call `srand(time(0));` **once** at the beginning of the program (preferably the first thing in `main()`).

Answer (score 1):

In C++11, you can do this with standard library facilities:
Imports:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(x));
```

This is the most basic way to sleep in a thread and works with multithreading.

Comment: @coolian - Click on the green check mark. Never forget to click on the green check mark.